# A complete set of driving rules in Norway

Tags: driving, norway

I am going to spend an extended period of time in Norway and will have to do quite a lot of driving. I wonder where could I find a complete set of driving rules in Norway (preferably in the form of a book or some sort of tutorial with a natural order that I could follow from A to Z)? The information could be either in English or in Norwegian.

I know in some countries there are specialized books that serve as tutorials for to-be drivers and include all the relevant information you need to know as a driver. I have tried searching a bit but only found some legal material regarding traffic (written in a legal language and thus hard to read) and some books which I was not quite sure about (I did not want to spend 30 to 50 bucks on a book just to find out it is not what I need).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a book to learn from and not just an English translation of the legal texts, you should try one of the course books used to teach new drivers by driving schools.

One of the most commonly used books is *'Veien til førerkortet: lærebok klasse B'* by Dagfinn Moe, Jarle Nermark and Kjell Torsmyr. You will be able to buy it in any Norwegian book shop and there are plenty of online shops selling the book. There is also an English translation of the same book titled *'The road to your driving licence: Car'*.

Comment: That might be just what I am looking for (+1). Could you give me any keywords I should use when looking for similar books? Or locations I should check? The one you recommend might be just fine, I am asking just in case. Takk skal du ha! ;)

Comment: @RichardHardy You could always search the online book stores for something like 'teoribok klasse B' (theory book, class B). A class B driver's license is for regular cars.

Answer (score 2):

Me think the basic driving rules are the same as in most "western" countries like in Europe and in North America.

This can help, from the Norwegian Public Roads Administration

https://www.vegvesen.no/en/traffic/Norwegian+rules+and+regulations/Traffic+rules

Click on the link to go to the PDF file (which you can save locally)

Comment: This is helpful, thank you (+1)! Ideally I would be looking for a more detailed set of rules, say, around 100 pages. There are small things that differ between countries and it is easy to earn a fine from a diligent policeman...

Comment: something like this : http://folk.uio.no/ponniahv/e-book/how-to-get-u-r-driving-licence-main-book.pdf